# Adding camera profile correction to dng_validate.exe [Adobe DNG SDK]

Tags: sdk, adobe, dng

Using Lightroom I know how to apply a camera profile (*.dcp file) to my *.DNG image.

I would like to do the same in an application which I'm writing, so I guess a good starting point would be to append this functionality to the dng_validate.exe application.

So I started to add:

```
#include "dng_camera_profile.h"
```

Then added:

```
static dng_string gDumpDCP;
```

And add the following to the error print:

```
"-dcp <file>   Load camera profile from <file>.dcp\"\n"
```

Then I added the function to read the dcp from cli:

```
else if (option.Matches("dcp", true))
{
   gDumpDCP.Clear();
   if (index + 1 < argc)
   {
      gDumpDCP.Set(argv[++index]);
   }

   if (gDumpDCP.IsEmpty() || gDumpDCP.StartsWith("-"))
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "*** Missing file name after -dcp\n");
      return 1;
   }

   if (!gDumpDCP.EndsWith(".dcp"))
   {
      gDumpDCP.Append(".dcp");
   }

}
```

Then I load the profile from disk [line 421]:

```
if (gDumpTIF.NotEmpty ())
{
   dng_camera_profile profile;
   if (gDumpDCP.NotEmpty())
   {
      dng_file_stream inStream(gDumpDCP.Get());
      profile.ParseExtended(inStream);
   }
   // Render final image.
   .... rest of code as it was
```

So how do I now use the profile data to correct the render and write the corrected image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after playing around for a couple of days, I now found the solution. Actually the negative can have multiple camera profiles. So with `negative->AddProfile(profile)` you just add one. But this won't be used if it's not the first profile! So we first need to clean the profiles and than add one.

```
AutoPtr<dng_camera_profile> profile(new dng_camera_profile);
if (gDumpDCP.NotEmpty())
{
    negative->ClearProfiles();
    dng_file_stream inStream(gDumpDCP.Get());
    profile->ParseExtended(inStream);

    profile->SetWasReadFromDNG();
    negative->AddProfile(profile);

    printf("Profile count: \"%d\"\n", negative->ProfileCount()); // will be 1 now!
}
```

Next thing to get the image correctly is to have correct white balance. This can be done in camera or afterwards. For my application with 4 different cameras, the result was the best when using afterward white balance correction. So I found 4 (Temperature,Tint) pairs using Lightroom.

The question was how to add these values in the dng_validate.exe program. I did it like this:

`#include "dng_temperature.h"`

```
if (gTemp != NULL && gTint != NULL)
{
    dng_temperature temperature(gTemp, gTint);
    render.SetWhiteXY(temperature.Get_xy_coord());
}
```

The resulting images are slightly different from the Lightroom result, but close enough. Also the camera to camera differences are gone now! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the profile to your negative with `negative->AddProfile(profile);`.

My project [raw2dng](https://github.com/Fimagena/raw2dng) does this (and more) and is available in source if you want to see an example. The profile is added [here](https://github.com/Fimagena/raw2dng/blob/master/raw2dng/negativeProcessor.cpp#L257).

Comment: I have compiled your program and generated an *.jpg from a DNG-file and pcf-file. The result is the same as I get from the dng_validate.exe. I also added the negative->AddProfile(profile) in the dng_validate.exe, but it doesn't change the output tiff. The files are different from the result of Lightroom. See:  [dng_validate_withProfile.jpg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s4o7tahqwxbtny1/dng_validate_withProfile.jpg?dl=0) [raw2dng.jpg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5z1c709bf480oy5/raw2dng.jpg?dl=0) [lightroom.jpg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/662tof9rfzurrv2/Lightroom.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: Running your program gave the following error for the dng file:  `- parsing raw file...`  
Error: Directory Nikon1 with 25665 entries considered invalid; not read.  For the RAW *.NEF file:  `- processing metadata...`  --> Error! (Invalid tag name or ifdId `ImageWidth', ifdId 83)

Comment: The original files: [image.dng](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7qac4cg0e5x6fqj/DSC_0806_adobeRGB_14bits.dng?dl=0),  [image.NEF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/if6c691y6d0d6tn/DSC_0806_adobeRGB_14bits.NEF?dl=0)  Camera profile: [nikon.dcp](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kq7o1d5jc523011/Nikon%20D5300_full_illumination.dcp?dl=0)   Camera profile converted to xml using dcpTool [nikon.xml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/por4qtfigmftqn9/nikon.xml?dl=0)

Comment: Also the output of raw2dng was the same for me with and without nikon.dcp. So from image.dng -> raw2dng.jpg. But in Lightroom the nikon.dcp file clearly improves the image.

Comment: The result is not wrong, it's just different. Developing a raw-file is not an exact science but involves all kinds of (partly camera-specific) assumptions. Seems like Adobe decided to apply some brightness boost to the NEF in Lightroom. If you use another professional raw-developer you might get slightly different results as well.